# Show only part of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has a height over 1000 pixels. I'd like to display it starting from a certain point, in this case, the scrollbar value.

I am assuming I need position:fixed for it + some coordinates.

I get the scrollbar position with this:

```
var pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

So, let's assume the value of the scrollTop is 350, and the height of the div is 1000, how do I show it up starting from 350?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try jquery scroll http://api.jquery.com/scroll/